# Как воспроизвести аудиопоток формата m3u в swift 4 x code

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Как воспроизвести аудиопоток формата m3u в swift 4 x code

Answer (score 1):

Через [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer), выглядит примерно так:

```
class LTPlayerController: UIViewController {

    private(set) var player: AVPlayer?

    func play() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://img3.1sell.com.ua/V/Image/Blog/Picture/9/Radio_24_04_2017.m3u")!
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.player?.play()
    }
}
```